# Force MassTransit DI (Bus) to be synchronously loaded before to be resolvable by other services

Tags: c#, masstransit

As part a of migration from MassTransit 7.x to  8.x was replaced this sentence:

`services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true);`

by:

```cs
 services.AddOptions<MassTransitHostOptions>()
  .Configure(options =>
  { 
    options.WaitUntilStarted = true;
  });
```

The MassTransit is the first service(resolvable dependency) in be registered/instanced because all data is being exchange through by a Bus services, therefore all Controllers requires the IPublisherEndPoint to publish information.  The problem is that all works fine in 7.3 but in 8.0.

The question is to avoid erros like this, where must be forced the MassTransit Bus to wait by its success instantiation?

---

Log:

- *System.AggregateException:
  Some services are not able to be constructed
  (Error while validating the service descriptor ServiceType: `Acme.Interface.IDummyService` Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: `Acme.Business.DummyService`:
  Unable to resolve service for type `MassTransit.IPublishEndpoint`
  while attempting to activate `Acme.Business.DummyService`.)*
- *(Error while validating the service descriptor ServiceType: `Acme.Business.DummyService` Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: `Acme.Business.DummyService`: Unable to resolve service for type `MassTransit.IPublishEndpoint` while attempting to activate `Acme.Business.DummyService`.)*

Notes: For this example: the service that requires the `IPublishEndpoint` service is named like: `Acme.Business.DummyService`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all of your associated dependencies updated to v8. It seems like you might have a dependent assembly that was built with a previous MassTransit version.